# HTML - Checkbox with other hidden values

Tags: html, checkbox

how do i submit the data from a checkbox with multiple values?

I have the followin data for a Checkbox:

```
- amount 
- name  
- checkbox (checked yes or no)
```

This is my checkbox code:

```
<input id="recipe_details-ingredient-6" name="ingredient[]" type="checkbox" value="6">
```

When the checkbox is checked, I submit value (id) to the controller, that's fine but how can I transfer the "name","amount" attributes also for THIS particular ID into the controller?

It's just a stupid question but I forgot how! Sorry :P

Comment: PHP, ASP.NET or ? How you send the checkbox value ? Show the related part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them in HTML5 data- attributes, for example, data-name in the following format:

```
<input id="{{$ingredient}}" name="ingredient[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$ingredient}}" data-name="{{name}}" style="display:inline-block;">
```

You can access the name by simply calling the .data() method in jQuery, i.e.

```
$('input').data('name').
```

edit

```
<input id="recipe_details-ingredient-6" name="ingredient[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$ingredient}}" data-name="{{name}}" style="display:inline-block;">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#recipe_details-ingredient-6").change(function(){
        $(this).val(); //get a val
        console.log($(this).attr('name')); //get a value of name attribute
    });
});
```

Comment: nice but I cannot get them to a php controller, right?